# OnChange not getting triggered on selecting value

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am trying to use Field from Formik and I am using `textfield` component in that. While selecting the value the `onChange` is not getting triggered.
Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Here is the code that I am trying:

```js
<Field
  component={TextField}
  type="text"
  name="selectedCustomer"
  label="Select Customer"
  select
  variant="standard"
  margin="normal"
  onChange={handleTextFieldChange}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
>
  {customerList.map(option => (
    <MenuItem key={uuidv4()} value={option.label}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Field>
```

Below is my `handleTextfieldChange` function:

```js
const handleTextFieldChange = event => {
  alert(event.target.value);
};
```